# DTO with class-transformer @Transform gives extra keys with nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, interceptor, class-transformer

I have two schemas `User` `Television`.
Using DTO to output fields needed only, but somehow it would give me nested keys.

For example my `user` object normally looks like

```json
{
    "createdAt": "2022-11-09T22:50:27.111Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-11-10T02:10:15.971Z",
    "_id": "636c2ee6142a0679a23b456f",
    "email": "dimitri.borer@yahoo.com",
    "name": "Ms. Jamie Douglas",
    "televisions": [
        {
            "createdAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "_id": "636c5d62cb4b24cc70fc44ed",
            "name": "Dietrich, Koelpin and Cassin",
            "website": "http://noemi.name",
            "stoppedAt": 843,
            "season": 191,
            "isCompleted": false
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "_id": "636c5d87cb4b24cc70fc4500",
            "name": "Howell - Koepp",
            "website": "http://marcella.biz",
            "stoppedAt": 663,
            "season": 237,
            "isCompleted": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a new route which would only return the televisions such as

```json
[
        {
            "createdAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "_id": "636c5d62cb4b24cc70fc44ed",
            "name": "Dietrich, Koelpin and Cassin",
            "website": "http://noemi.name",
            "stoppedAt": 843,
            "season": 191,
            "isCompleted": false
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-10T02:09:33.364Z",
            "_id": "636c5d87cb4b24cc70fc4500",
            "name": "Howell - Koepp",
            "website": "http://marcella.biz",
            "stoppedAt": 663,
            "season": 237,
            "isCompleted": false
        }
    ]
```

I thought by doing `user.televisions` would give me that output with this `user-tv.dto.ts`

```js
import { Expose, plainToInstance, Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { Television } from '../../televisions/television.entity';

class TvDto {
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  website: string;

  @Expose()
  stoppedAt: number;

  @Expose()
  season: number;

  @Expose()
  isCompleted: boolean;
}

export class UserTvDto {
  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ obj }) => {
    return plainToInstance(TvDto, obj, {
      excludeExtraneousValues: true,
    });
  })
  televisions: Television[];
}
```

I would get this as return

```json
[
    {
        "televisions": {
            "name": "Dietrich, Koelpin and Cassin",
            "website": "http://noemi.name",
            "stoppedAt": 843,
            "season": 191,
            "isCompleted": false
        }
    },
    {
        "televisions": {
            "name": "Howell - Koepp",
            "website": "http://marcella.biz",
            "stoppedAt": 663,
            "season": 237,
            "isCompleted": false
        }
    }
]
```

I got array of objects and each contains televisions as the key, how can I get rid of the televisions key and have it as array of objects `[{}, {}]` instead?

This is how my `SerializeInterceptor` looks like

```js
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

export function Serialize(dto) {
  return UseInterceptors(new SerializeInterceptor(dto));
}

@Injectable()
export class SerializeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private dto: any) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        return plainToInstance(this.dto, data, {
          excludeExtraneousValues: true,
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

how my controller looks like for this route

```js
  @Serialize(UserTvDto)
  @Get('/televisions')
  televisions(@CurrentUser() user: User) {
    return user.televisions;
  }
```

I wonder how can I have the output without having all object having the key of `televisions`?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices